# UI alignment issue for eSign using REST API

Tags: docusignapi

We are facing an alignment issue while doing eSignature. Our PDF is aligned Right.
We are using an iFrame to show DocuSign Signature controls and PDF and it is aligning to right.
We have used the same code in our staging environment and it has no alignment issue there.

Can you please help us in fixing this? Please refer the below screenshot:

Thank you in advance.[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDuch.png)

We tried docusign setting with docusign login

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you try to use the new feature just released by DocuSign called "[Focused View](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/15-minutes-to-better-ux-enhancing-embedded-signing-focused-view)" which allows you to use a DIV instead of an iframe and make more subtle changes to the embedded signing expereince.
To use this feature you need to make slight modifications in the REST API call, but also you need to add a javascript file to your HTML code and make a call, like this:

```
  window.DocuSign.loadDocuSign("your_integration_key_guid_here")
    .then((docusign) => {
      const signing = docusign.signing({...});
      ...
    })
    .catch((ex) => {
      // Any configuration or API limits will be caught here
    });
</script>
```

[How-to request signature with Focused View](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-focused-view/)